# NSLayoutConstraint subviews won't autoresize to fit container view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple layout where there is a `containerView` that starts on the entire screen. Inside, I have two vertical subviews — `topView (green), botView (orange)` which need equal heights and should have 50% of the `containerView` height.

After launch, I slide in a view (blue) from offscreen up from the bottom, causing the `containerView` to resize to a shorter height.

What I would expect to happen is that the `topView` and `botView` would both get shorter, maintaining their even heights within the `containerView`, but what actually happens is that the inner views are not resized, despite having a constraint to do so.

[image]

Because this code has some code based constraints, and some IB ones, [here](http://cloud.coneybeare.net/QYy9) is a sample project to see it in action. This is the constraint which is being ignored:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.containerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:0.5f
                                                       constant:0.f];
[self.containerView addConstraint:c1];
```

and the resize view code:

```
- (void)resizeViews {

    __weak UAViewController *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            weakSelf.slideInView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(weakSelf.view.bounds),
                                                    CGRectGetMaxY(weakSelf.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.slideInView.frame),
                                                    CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.view.bounds),
                                                    CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.slideInView.frame));

            weakSelf.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(weakSelf.view.bounds),
                                                      CGRectGetMinY(weakSelf.view.bounds),
                                                      CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.view.bounds),
                                                      CGRectGetMaxY(weakSelf.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.slideInView.frame));

        }];
    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By the way, why are you doing `dispatch_async` in `resizeViews`? That's not necessary (unless you're calling it from some other queue, which I'd be surprised if you're doing that). But it's moot, since if you're doing autolayout, you shouldn't be mucking around with `frame` properties at all. Modify your constraints, and let the constraint engine make the appropriate `frame` changes.

Comment: dispatch_async is being called from a timer thread for this debug app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised you're setting the `frame` for a view. Generally in auto layout, you'd slide in the view by changing a constraint `constant`, not by changing a `frame`.

For example, imagine that your constraints for the container's subviews are defined like so (for simplicity's sake, since the two views are supposed to take up 50% of the container, most easily done by defining the two subviews to be the same height):

```
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topView][botView(==topView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[topView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[botView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

And, to keep things simple, define the relation between the container, the slide in view with relation to their superview like so:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView][slideInView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[slideInView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

// set the slide in view's initial height to zero

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:slideInView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

Then, when you want to slide in the "slide in view", just animate the changing of its height accordingly:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Thus:

[image: two views]

Now, you can do this with heights that are x% of the height of the container, too, but you just can't do that easily with VFL, but it should work fine. Also you could slide in that "slide in view" by animating its top constraint, too (but that's a hassle because then you have to recalculate the top constraint on rotation, something I didn't want to do in this simple mockup).

But you get the idea. Just define the height or bottom constraint of the container view to be in relation to the slide in view, and then animate the slide in view by adjusting its constraints, and if you've defined all of your constraints properly, it will gracefully animate all four views (the container, the slide in view, and the container's two subviews) properly when you animate `layoutIfNeeded` after changing the slide in view's constraints.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense and I have applied the changes to my proj, but I have not been able to replicate your screenshots — "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints". Can you pass back the modified proj that you used here so I can learn where I am going wrong?

Comment: @coneybeare Usually an inability to satisfy constraints is a result of neglecting to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for your programmatically created views. I must confess that I haven't looked at your project (it can sometimes be hairy going through someone else's project) and it was easier to just do this from scratch. I just created a blank app, and threw the following code in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`: http://pastie.org/8194565# Hopefully that illustrates the concept.

Comment: I was able to duplicate your results by using the pastie code, but I am struggling to understand why the same thing is not working when using views generated by IB. I set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on all 5 views, don't have any constraints in the storyboard, yet continue to get the error. Can you just peek at this (very simple) example proj? http://cloud.coneybeare.net/QZ6G

Comment: My theory is that views instantiated from IB have system defined frame size constraints auto-applied, but I don't see an option to prevent the auto creation of these.

Comment: @coneybeare No, I don't think that is the case. But Interface Builder in Xcode 4.6 can be infuriating in its continual attempt to add constraints in its effort to try to eliminate ambiguities. Xcode 5 is much better in that regard. But I find that I'm generally able to wrestle IB in Xcode 4.6 to do it right. I'll take a look at your project tonight.

Comment: I am using XC5 :/ I decided to press on with a code generated UI though, something I am much more comfortable with. New problem though if you want to take a stab at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982834/combining-nslayoutconstraints-with-calayer-backed-views-does-not-animate-correct

Comment: @coneybeare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34577/discussion-between-rob-and-coneybeare)